# SQLite Syntax Error near "RETURNING" (Node)

Tags: node-sqlite3, sql-returning

I got a Node script with an Express server, im trying to insert a new entry into a Table.
If got folloing setup:

```
db.run('CREATE TABLE lists(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL)');
...
db.get(`INSERT INTO lists (name) VALUES (?) RETURNING *;`, [name], (err, row) => {
        ...
    });
```

And the Insert statement throws:

```
Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "RETURNING": syntax error
--> in Database#get('INSERT INTO lists (name) VALUES (?) RETURNING *;', [ 'Testing' ], [Function (anonymous)])
```

but this should be working according to the sqlite [wiki](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

any advise?

Comment: What version of Sqlite are you using? (The Sqlite engine version, not the npm package version)

Comment: My package.json states: 
```
"sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
```

Comment: sqlite> select sqlite_version();
3.36.0 @Dai

Comment: The version `3.36.0` you see is from the Sqlite command-line interface, that's not the same version of Sqlite that's being loaded into NodeJS.

Comment: if i run the command with nodeJs the verison ist 3.34.0

Comment: There's your problem. You need Sqlite version **3.35** to use `RETURNING`.

Comment: Ok thanks how do i specify the version of the SQLite Version is there an option to specify it? @Dai

Comment: See my answer. Assuming you have `sqlite3` version `5.0.2` configured (check your `package.json` file) then you likely have a corrupt npm package cache or some older files sticking around, in which case that's a different problem you should post a new question for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Support for the `RETURNING` clause was added in Sqlite 3.35.

  - https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_35_0.html

    > "Add support for the RETURNING clause on DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements."
- While you have Sqlite 3.36 installed in your operating system's environment, it seems your Node environment has an older version of the `sqlite3` npm package which has Sqlite 3.34.
- On GitHub, as of early November 2021, the `sqlite3` package version `5.0.2` for npm was released in February 2021 with an older version of Sqlite.

  - There is no public release of the `node-sqlite3` package with Sqlite 3.36 yet.
  - [`node-sqlite3` does have a commit that updated Sqlite to 3.36](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/commit/bc5d794cd7407a1aa55321fbeec3b3cf77fdc2eb) but no release has been made yet.

Comment: Thanks I see the problem but i can't find where my npm is not working even after a npm cach verify and npm update the sqlite engine is still 3.34 any advise?

Comment: @Sifi_crafter I have no further advice, sorry.

Comment: The engine version for sqlite3 is not updated in the release v5.0.2 because the commit you showed is from 25 days ago but the release is from february

Comment: @Sifi_crafter Whoops, sorry, I clicked the wrong link in the GitHub release page - I thought I was looking at "commits **in** this release" -  I was actually looking at commits **after** that release.